# I need help limiting groupby to return values within a specific range and plotting the mean values from each year on a line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am trying to plot the mean max and min values per year between the 2005-2014 onto a line graph. The database I am reading from has 165085 rows with the recorded temperature from numerous weather stations

To solve this problem I converted the Date column into timestamp format and then used the groupby function to return Data Values grouped by the element column (there are two elements TMAX and TMIN) and then plotted these two (TMAX and TMIN) onto a line chart.

There are 2 problems:
1.) the line chart shows data points from each row on the dataframe- I think it would make more sense showing the mean maximum and minimum temperature for each year
2.) I want to show the mean min and max temperatures between 2005 and 2014 (my chart shows the min and mix temps between 2005 and 2015)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv') 
#converting dates into datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Element')['Data_Value'].plot.line(legend=True)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
plt.show()
```

This is my current output:

[image]

Tables sample:

```
    ID  Element Data_Value
Date            
2014-11-12  USW00094889 TMAX    22
2009-04-29  USC00208972 TMIN    56
2008-05-26  USC00200032 TMAX    278
2005-11-11  USC00205563 TMAX    139
2014-02-27  USC00200230 TMAX    -106
2010-10-01  USW00014833 TMAX    194
2010-06-29  USC00207308 TMIN    144
2005-10-04  USC00203712 TMAX    289
2007-12-14  USW00004848 TMIN    -16
2011-04-21  USC00200220 TMAX    72
2013-01-16  USC00205822 TMAX    11
2008-05-29  USC00205822 TMIN    28
```

Comment: There are two separate, unrelated questions (one on fixing your output, and another on plotting it). Can you limit your post to one question per post please.

Comment: @coldspeed Maybe I don't understanding what you mean but these seem like related problems- i.) looking at the mean min and max values, ii.) between 2005 and 2014 and plotting those to a line chart. The plotting part isn't the problem

Comment: The code isn't runnable (see [mcve]) and the picture is broken. So one has little chance of seeing the problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest added a picture of my output and a sample of the database i am reading from, hope this helps?

Comment: I would try something like `.resample('Y', how='mean')`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your table sample

```py
>>> df = df.pivot(columns='Element', values='Data_Value')
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
>>> df = df.resample('YS').mean()
>>> df

Element     TMAX    TMIN
Date        
2005-01-01  214.0   NaN
2006-01-01  NaN     NaN
2007-01-01  NaN     -16.0
2008-01-01  278.0   28.0
2009-01-01  NaN     56.0
2010-01-01  194.0   144.0
2011-01-01  72.0    NaN
2012-01-01  NaN     NaN
2013-01-01  11.0    NaN
2014-01-01  -42.0   NaN
```

From here it's easy to plot each column using `df.plot()`

```py
>>> df.plot(marker='o', lw=0)
```

**Output**
[image: Plot output]